# NODE.js MongoDB have different clients get multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This may have been asked before, how does one connect to a mongoDB / node.js server from a client? For me, in order to access anything in the mongoDB database, I need to first log in:

```
client.connect(mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0-cvkxs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true, {"useNewUrlParser":true}, (e, db) => {
   //do mongoDB stuff and send things, and store db.db variable elsewhere, to send db.db("database").collection("something") to websocket clients when they verified / requested it...
}
```

the thing is, in order to get anything from the database, I have to conncet to it using my admin user, and if multiple connections are made to it, then the other ones are logged out automatically.

SO if every time a websocket client connects and wants to get data from the database, then all of the other ones would automatically be logged out of the database (the database object is being copied / passed to the websocket client itself, like on connection I do: ws.customDB = db, after logging on for each client).

SO how can I connect the clients to the database so that multiple people can access it at the same time (with different privileges)?
Just to explain a bit more, here's my complete node.js code:

```
var web = require("ws");
var wss = new web.Server({port:process.env.PORT || 8080});
var mongo = require("mongodb");
var client = mongo.MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@cluster0-cvkxs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
var DB = null;
var functionsToDo = {  
  "login":(ws, data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var u, p;
    [[u, p] = [data["username"],data["password"]]];
    if(u && p) {
        tryToConnectToDB({"user":u,"pass":p}, (err, db) => {
            var message = {
                "loginCode":1
            };
            if(err) {
                var errors = err["errors"];
                if(errors) {
                    message["harsh errors"] = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                        if(errors[i]["err"]["code"] == 8000) {
                            message["loginCode"] = 0;
                            console.log("Wrong username or password!");
                        }
                        message["harsh errors"].push(errors[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
            if(db) {
                DB = db;
                ws.myDB = db.db("cobysdata")
                ws.mainDB = db;
                ws.mainDB.on("close", () => {
                    ws.send(JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        "databaseStatus":"closed"
                    }
                    ));
                });
                console.log("user " + data["username"] + " just logged on to this database:");
            }

            ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            });
        }
    },
    "get users":(ws, data) => {
        functionsToDo["do database command"](ws, {wantResponse:"users",command:"find", collection:"people","query":{}});
    },
    "do database command":(ws, data) => {
        tryToDoAction(ws, data, () => {
            console.log("trying to do this with: " + data);
            if(data["command"]) {
                var c = data["command"];
                var func = (e, r) => {
                    var msg = {};
                    if(e) {
                      console.log(e);  
                      msg["harsh errors"] = "You got an error or something";
                    }
                    else {
                        msg[data["wantResponse"] || "your data"] = r;
                        msg["success"] = true;
                        try {
                        ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
                        } catch(e) {
                            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                                message:"There was a success, but you could not display the results.",
                                success:true
                            }));
                            console.log(e, "bad msg?", msg);
                        }
                    }
                };

                var empt = {};
                var curr = data["updateQuery"] || func;

                var query = data["query"] || empt,
                    newvalues = data["new values"] || empt;
                var col;
                if(c != "createCollection")
                    col = ws.myDB.collection(data["collection"]);
                else {
                   col = ws.myDB; 
                }
                var commands = {
                    "find": {
                        "names": {
                            "find":["query"],
                            "toArray":["callback"]
                        }
                    },
                    "sort": {
                        "names": {
                            "find":[],
                            "sort":["query"],
                            "toArray":["callback"]
                          }                          
                    },
                    "limit": {
                        "names": {
                            "find":[],
                            "limit":["number"],
                            "toArray":["callback"]
                          }                          
                    },
                    "deleteOne": {
                        "args":["query","callback"]
                    },
                    "findOne": {
                        "args":["query", "callback"]
                    },
                    "insertOne": {
                        "args":["query", "callback"]
                    },
                    "insertMany": {
                        "args":["array"]
                    },
                    "remove": {
                        "args":["query", "callback"]
                    },
                    "drop": {
                        "args":["callback"]
                    },
                    "updateOne": {
                        "args":["query", "newvalues", "callback"]
                    },
                    "aggregate": {
                        "args": ["query"],
                        "hasCB":"toArray"
                    },
                    "createCollection": {
                        "args":["string", "callback"]
                    }
                };
                var otherDictionary = {
                    "query":query,
                    "callback":func,
                    "string":query,
                    "newvalues":newvalues,
                    "array":query,
                    "number":query
                };

                var val = commands[c];
                var funcList, arguments;
                if(val) {
                    funcList = [];
                    var n = val["names"];
                    if(n) {
                        for(var k in n) {
                            var functionName = k,
                                arguments = [];
                            n[k].forEach(x=>arguments.push(otherDictionary[x]));
                            funcList.push([functionName,arguments]);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        n = val["args"];
                        if(n) {
                            arguments = [];
                            n.forEach(x => {
                                arguments.push(otherDictionary[x]);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("functions: ", JSON.stringify(funcList));
                    if(funcList.length > 0)
                        console.log(funcList.reduce((a, [key, args]) => a[key](...args), col));
                    else
                        console.log(console.log(col[c](...arguments)));


                }
               // col(query)["toArray"];

            } else {
                console.log("no command");
            }
        });
    },
};

function tryToDoAction(ws, data, whatToDo) {
    if(ws.myDB != null ) {
        try {
            whatToDo();
        } catch(e) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                "medium error":e
            }));
            console.log(e);
            }

    } else {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            "message":"Hey, you're not authorized to do that, log in first!!"
        }));
        console.log("Something happened");
    }    
}

function tryToConnectToDB(obj, cb) {
    if(obj["user"] && obj["pass"]) {
        var URL = `mongodb+srv://${obj["user"]}:${obj["pass"]}@cluster0-cvkxs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`;
        client.connect(URL, {
                                reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
                                reconnectInterval: 1000,
                                "useNewUrlParser":true
                            }, (err, db) => {
            cb(err, db);
        });
    }
}



wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    ws.stillGoing = true;
    var num = wss.clients.size;
    console.log("clienfs",num);
    var orig = {
        "number of others":num
    };
    var ms = JSON.stringify(orig)
    console.log("sending: ", ms, orig);
    ws.send(ms);
    ws.on("pong", () => ws.stillGoing = true);
    console.log("Someone just connected!");
    ws.on("message", (msg) => {
        console.log("Checking this: ", msg, typeof msg);
        var j = tryToParse(msg);
        console.log("this is that tried to be parsed (or not): ", j);
        for(var k in j) {
            if(functionsToDo[k]) {
                functionsToDo[k](ws, (j[k]));
            }
        }    
    });

    ws.on("close", (ws) => {
        console.log("Someone just left :(");
        try {
            ws.myDB = null;
            DB.close(); 
        } catch(e) {
        }
    });
});

var inter = setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach(x => {
       if(!x.stillGoing) {
           x.terminate(); 
           console.log("terminating the terminator");
       }
       x.stillGoing = false;
       x.ping(() => {});
    });
}, 10 * 1000);



function tryToParse(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return {};
    }
}

function isJSON(string) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(string);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I faced the same issue, in documentation i found the solution, here is my blog. 
https://medium.com/@maharjun123/crud-operations-of-mongodb-using-node-server-with-help-of-mongoose-8e59bd76b296 you can refere this

Comment: @MaharjunM Hi very interesting article; however I prefer not to use express or mongoose, do you know how to solve this without that?